# Space and time complexity of nested loop function

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

I recently had a discussion with a colleague on space and time complexity of some trivial bit of code and we disagreed on both. The disagreement actually made me question myself and so asking here for clarification. The following has both, my understanding of how it should be derived and their counter-arguments.

Assume we have a Data-Structure which is a List of Lists of integers. The following is in python but hopefully understandable by non-python people:

```
# A function that takes a parameter called outer_list of type
# list of lists of integers.
def stupid_foo(outer_list: list[list[int]]) {
    new_outer_list: list = []

    # For every element in outer list
    for inner_list in outer_list:
        new_inner_list: list = []

        # For every element in inner list
        for integer_element in inner_list:
             new_inner_list.append(integer_element)

        new_outer_list.append(new_inner_list)
}
```

##### Time complexity:

My understanding is it's `O(n*m)` (or say `O(n^2)` to keep it simple assuming the size of outer list and each inner list is `n` elements big) - ie. quadratic. Reason being that for every element of outer list you operate on `n` elements of inner list. So the total number of operations is `n + n + n + ... + n` n-times = `n^2`. However they argued that:

> The time complexity of this function that is exactly linear in the size of the input since it touches everything exactly once

While I was fairly convinced it's quadratic, I'm now second-guessing if I'm right. Which one is it?

##### Space Complexity:

My interpretation of a conformant definition ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity)) is that it's represented as the total space taken by the algorithm. There's also a convention to discard space occupied by input itself ([StackExchange link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/156952)). Either way, I'm interpreting this as the relation between the amount of additional space taken by the algorithm and the space taken by the input to the algorithm. Assuming the size of references/pointers/loop-variables etc are constant and can be ignored, this algorithm should have a linear space complexity, ie. `O(n)`. My reasoning is that for a given input-size of `n` units, the algorithm allocates an additional `n` units. So if the input is `250B` the upper bound for memory is an additional `250B` and so on.

However their answer is that it should be `O(n*m)` (or `O(n^2)` if we assume `n==m` for simplicity, where `n` is the number of elements in outer and each inner list) - ie quadratic.

However my interpretation is that space complexity has little to do with the data-structure and more to do with how the overall space occupied by algorithm varies as a function of space taken by the input. `O(n^2)` could be the number of operations that the above algorithm *potentially* performs to eventually occupy twice the space occupied by the input, but I don't think that's how Space-Complexity is represented.

In other words, if someone told me that the space complexity of an algorithm was quadratic (just like how time complexity was derived in this case above), I would assume that if I supplied `250B` of input, it would occupy a peak memory size of additional `(250^2)B`.

Again, which one of us is more conformant and are the reasons given above valid?

#### Edit

So after a [brief chat in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76209326/space-and-time-complexity-of-nested-loop-function/76210260?noredirect=1#comment134396290_76210260) I suppose it boils down to whether my assumption of the convention is correct, in that when talking about time-complexity, variables such as `n` represent the number of elements whereas for space-complexity `n` would represent the unit of space occupied by the input (and not the number of elements or their arrangement in a given data-structure that eventually leads to that space being occupied). My conclusion of quadratic complexity for time and linear complexity for space in the above question hinges on this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

As you note, it’s both linear in the size of the input (assuming no sharing; the outer list could be n aliases of the same inner list) and quadratic in the length of the lists – no contradiction there. So then it’s a question of what “linear” means without context, and I would agree with your friend that the implicit variable is the size of the input.

Comment: Thanks! Could you clarify if you are talking about the time or the space complexity? Just to make sure I understand properly (as I ask questions about each of them).

Comment: @ustulation both. The detail with whether the input counts or not doesn't matter here since we're copying it.

Comment: So what would be the conventional answer for time and space complexity for this algorithm in big-O? Or is there no conventional notation? To me the time taken to process the input quadratic-ally increases with the size of the input - eg. if i was trying to find a particular element (same as copying element by element). If instead the inner structure was a hash-map, then those lookups would be `O(1)` (assuming no collisions) and the time would be linear on the size of the outer list. Is it wrong to say that the correct representation of the time complexity for the original post is `O(n*m)`?

Comment: Similarly for the space complexity, is it wrong to say the conformant/conventional definition is that it's a representation of relation of space taken by the algorithm wrt to the space taken by the input to the algorithm? In that case it seems it should be linear on space - so `O(n)` where `n` is no longer the number of elements, but simply the overall unit (bytes?) of space taken. Or is there no convention as such?

Comment: @ustulation usually if there's possible confusion about what n could be, you should say what n is. So O(n) (where n is the size of the input) or O(m n) (where the input consists of m lists, each of length n).

Comment: @ustulation conventionally the default unit of space on the default model (the unit-cost RAM, not a Turing machine, sorry complexity theorists) is words (e.g., one pointer).

Comment: "usually if there's possible confusion about what n could be" : Exactly, I think this is what it comes down to and is likely an important part of my question. That in the _conformant_ definition of time complexity, `n,m,..` etc are the number of elements, whereas for space complexity it's the unit of space taken by input. However if there's no such "conformant" definition, then I agree, that the notations need to have more metadata associated to detail what exactly is meant by `n, m..` etc.

Comment: So I think my question boils down to whether or not I'm correct in assuming those ^^^ to be the conformant definitions and thus the (different) default meaning associated with `n` in the context of time complexity and the context of space complexity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253568/discussion-between-david-eisenstat-and-ustulation).